# Equation of the intersection of two circles

Tags: geometry, circles

I'd like to find the equation that describes the intersection between two circles. I'm having some trouble though. 
What I've thought of doing is to write down the two inequalities of the 2 circles, something like this:

$$(x-x_0)^2  +  (y-y_0)^2   <   r_0^2$$
$$(x-x_1)^2  +  (y-y_1)^2   <   r_1^2$$

where the first circle is centered in $(x_0, y_0)$ with a radius of $r_0$, and the second one is centered in $(x_1, y_1)$ with a radius of $r_1$.

I can't seem to solve this, though, and I'm not sure whether I'm missing some other condition or if this is perfectly fine and I'm just failing at solving it.
Thank you!

Comment: http://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/GeometryConicSectionCircleIntersection.aspx  refer to this link.  It gives you the proof too.

Comment: Thank you! This only explains how you find the two points of intersection though. What I would actually need to find is, if possible, the inequality/equation describing the whole area of intersection. This might not be clear from my explanation though, so I'll update it.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html would work

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"? Your two equations describe the interior of the intersection. What more do you want? There are obviously infinitely many points (x,y) in the intersection.